# slimScroll not draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using slimScroll for one of my site. Now everything is working except the draagable feature. I cannot drag the scroll bar. But I am able to scroll it using scroll wheel. Please check the issue here. http://bit.ly/xlxutn

Comment: Do you initialize the plugin before the content is populated ? Maybe you need to refresh it after content is loaded. Have you tried another plugin, like jScrollPane for instance? It offers a much more complete API.

Comment: I have moved the initializations to the bottom and so it will be called only after the content is loaded. But no change, It is still nto draggable. I  have tried the jScrollPane. But it is messing up with the design as there is some other css codes based on the slimScroll classes.

Comment: Moving the code to the bottom is not sufficient if you are loading content via ajax! You should put it in the success callback to be sure the content is loaded when you init the plugin. Nevertheless, I'm just suggesting, I don't know if this will resolve your problem.

Comment: I have tried it all but still have the issue...any help form anyone..? please check the link so that you can see the page

Comment: Update : When add the draggable to the div from firebug console, it is dragging. But not scrolling. So i think there is no conflict between the libraries.

Comment: query: Hi, I saw your link and seems you have solved the problem, can you please help me too? I m stuck in the same loop Thanks

Comment: Actually I have only changed the order in adding the scripts and that fixes the issue. I put slimscroll JS just after the jquery and drag-gable files

Answer (score 1):

You can update. It seems that you had a jquery ui version conflict. Current version does not depend on jquery ui.

Comment: So please be kind enough to provide your solution and mark it as a solution. (I could not see your comment)

Comment: where is the solution i couldn't able to find the solution in this page... :) Can you send me the link for perfect solution...